# How to display many text input fields in libgdx at a random position on the main window?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to display many text input fields with libgdx (like for example 
Name, Surname, email) where the user has to input those info.
I've tried following this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Simple-text-input but it's not the best option in my case both because I want it to be included in the main window instead of opening a new little one and because it displays only one text input field.
Moreover i want to be able to make those fields appear at random position on the main window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scene2d widget for your requirement, Create Label and TextField and add to stage. You can use Table for arrangement of your Actors.

```
public class Splash extends Game  {

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        ExtendViewport extendViewport=new ExtendViewport(700,1200,new OrthographicCamera());
        stage=new Stage(extendViewport);

        Skin skin=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));
        skin.get("font-label", BitmapFont.class).getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

        Table table=new Table();
        table.defaults().pad(10);
        table.setFillParent(true);

        Label userName=new Label("USER ID : ",skin);
        TextField userNameField=new TextField("",skin);

        Label name =new Label("NAME : ",skin);
        TextField nameField=new TextField("",skin);

        Label email=new Label("EMAIL : ",skin);
        TextField emailField=new TextField("",skin);

        table.add(userName);
        table.add(userNameField).width(300);
        table.row();
        table.add(name).left();
        table.add(nameField).width(300);
        table.row();
        table.add(email).left();
        table.add(emailField).width(300);

        stage.addActor(table);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.draw();
        stage.act();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width,height);
        stage.getViewport().update(width,height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
       stage.dispose();
    }
```

Output looks :

[image]